# Acumatica - Processing Screen Not Executing Process Delegate for Selected Records

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a processing screen in Acumatica ERP (2020R2). Whenever I run Process All, it executes the process delegate correctly. But whenever I select some of the records and run the Process action, the process delegate doesn't even get called.

I've implemented several processing screens, and I've never had this problem.

I did notice that, when I click the Selected checkbox, a red dot appears beside the row on the grid and doesn't go away. On other processing screens that I've implemented, the red dot appears then goes away.

Here is my graph:

```
    public class StkItemUpdateProcess : PXGraph<StkItemUpdateProcess>
    {
        #region Fliter DAC

        [PXHidden]
        public class StkItemFilter : IBqlTable
        {
            #region UpdateID
            [PXString(15, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update ID")]
            [PXSelector(
                typeof(SearchFor<StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID>),
                typeof(StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID),
                typeof(StkItemUpdateHdr.descr),
                typeof(StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID),
                typeof(StkItemUpdateHdr.effectiveDate)
            )]
            public virtual string UpdateID { get; set; }
            public abstract class updateID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<updateID> { }
            #endregion

            #region VendorID
            [PXInt]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Vendor")]
            [PXSelector(
                typeof(
                    SearchFor<Vendor.bAccountID>.
                        In<SelectFrom<Vendor>.
                            InnerJoin<Address>.
                                On<Address.addressID.IsEqual<Vendor.defAddressID>>.
                            Where<Vendor.status.IsEqual<BAccount.status.active>>>
                ),
                typeof(Vendor.acctCD),
                typeof(Vendor.acctName),
                typeof(Address.city),
                typeof(Address.state),
                SubstituteKey = typeof(Vendor.acctCD),
                DescriptionField = typeof(Vendor.acctName)
            )]
            public virtual int? VendorID { get; set; }
            public abstract class vendorID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<vendorID> { }
            #endregion

            #region InventoryID
            [PXInt]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
            [PXSelector(
                typeof(
                    SearchFor<InventoryItem.inventoryID>.
                        In<SelectFrom<InventoryItem>.
                            InnerJoin<POVendorInventory>.
                                On<POVendorInventory.inventoryID.IsEqual<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>.
                            Where<InventoryItem.stkItem.IsEqual<True>.
                                And<POVendorInventory.vendorID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID.FromCurrent>>.
                                And<POVendorInventory.active.IsEqual<True>>>>
                ),
                typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
                typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
                typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
                typeof(InventoryItem.itemType),
                SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD)
            )]
            [PXRestrictor(
                typeof(Where<InventoryItem.stkItem.IsEqual<True>.
                            And<POVendorInventory.vendorID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID.FromCurrent>>.
                            And<POVendorInventory.active.IsEqual<True>>>),
                Messages.InvalidVendorItemPair)]
            public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
            public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
            #endregion

            #region FromEffectiveDate
            [PXDate]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "From Date")]
            [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            public virtual DateTime? FromEffectiveDate { get; set; }
            public abstract class fromEffectiveDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<fromEffectiveDate> { }
            #endregion

            #region ToEffectiveDate
            [PXDate]
            [PXUIField(DisplayName = "To Date")]
            [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.businessDate), PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
            public virtual DateTime? ToEffectiveDate { get; set; }
            public abstract class toEffectiveDate : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<toEffectiveDate> { }
            #endregion
        }

        #endregion

        #region Selects / Views

        public PXCancel<StkItemFilter> Cancel;

        public PXFilter<StkItemFilter> Filter;

        public PXFilteredProcessingJoin<StkItemUpdateDet, StkItemFilter,
            InnerJoin<StkItemUpdateHdr, 
                On<StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateDet.updateID>>, 
            InnerJoin<Vendor, 
                On<Vendor.bAccountID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID>>,
            InnerJoin<InventoryItem, 
                On<InventoryItem.inventoryID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateDet.inventoryID>>>>>,
            Where<Brackets<StkItemFilter.updateID.FromCurrent.IsNull.
                    Or<StkItemUpdateDet.updateID.IsEqual<StkItemFilter.updateID.FromCurrent>>>.
                And<StkItemFilter.vendorID.FromCurrent.IsNull.
                    Or<StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID.IsEqual<StkItemFilter.vendorID.FromCurrent>>>.
                And<StkItemFilter.inventoryID.FromCurrent.IsNull.
                    Or<StkItemUpdateDet.inventoryID.IsEqual<StkItemFilter.inventoryID.FromCurrent>>>.
                And<StkItemFilter.fromEffectiveDate.FromCurrent.IsNull.
                    Or<StkItemUpdateHdr.effectiveDate.IsGreaterEqual<StkItemFilter.fromEffectiveDate.FromCurrent>>>.
                And<StkItemFilter.toEffectiveDate.FromCurrent.IsNull.
                    Or<StkItemUpdateHdr.effectiveDate.IsLessEqual<StkItemFilter.toEffectiveDate.FromCurrent>>>>, 
            OrderBy<Desc<StkItemUpdateHdr.effectiveDate, Asc<StkItemUpdateDet.updateID, Asc<Vendor.acctCD, Asc<InventoryItem.inventoryCD>>>>>>
            StkItemUpdates;

        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public StkItemUpdateProcess()
        {
            StkItemUpdates.SetProcessCaption("Update");
            StkItemUpdates.SetProcessTooltip("Update Selected Stock Items");
            StkItemUpdates.SetProcessAllCaption("Update All");
            StkItemUpdates.SetProcessAllTooltip("Update All Stock Items");
            StkItemUpdates.SetProcessDelegate(UpdateStkItems);
            StkItemUpdates.SetSelected<StkItemUpdateDet.selected>();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Overrides

        public override bool IsDirty => false;

        #endregion

        #region Event Handlers

        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldUpdated<StkItemFilter, StkItemFilter.updateID> e)
        {
            if (e.Row == null) return;
            StkItemFilter filter = Filter.Current;

            if(filter.UpdateID != null)
            {
                StkItemUpdateHdr hdr =
                    SelectFrom<StkItemUpdateHdr>.
                        Where<StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID.IsEqual<@P.AsString>>.
                    View.ReadOnly.Select(e.Cache.Graph, filter.UpdateID);

                e.Cache.SetValueExt<StkItemFilter.vendorID>(filter, hdr?.VendorID);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void _(Events.FieldSelecting<StkItemUpdateDet, StkItemUpdateDet.defaultVendor> e)
        {
            if (e.Row == null) return;

            StkItemUpdateDet det = e.Row;

            PXResultset<POVendorInventory> existingVendors =
                SelectFrom<POVendorInventory>.
                    Where<POVendorInventory.inventoryID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>.
                View.ReadOnly.Select(e.Cache.Graph, det.InventoryID);

            //IsDefault cannot be used in BQL statement because it is not bound.
            foreach (POVendorInventory vendor in existingVendors)
            {
                if (vendor.IsDefault == true)
                {
                    e.ReturnValue = vendor.VendorID;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Actions

        public PXAction<StkItemFilter> OpenUpdate;
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open Update")]
        public virtual void openUpdate()
        {
            StkItemUpdateDet det = StkItemUpdates.Current;
            StkItemUpdateMaint stkItemUpdateMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<StkItemUpdateMaint>();
            stkItemUpdateMaint.UpdateHdr.Current = stkItemUpdateMaint.UpdateHdr.Search<StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID>(det.UpdateID);
            if (stkItemUpdateMaint.UpdateHdr.Current != null) 
            {
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(stkItemUpdateMaint, true, "Stock Item Update")
                {
                    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
                };
            } 
        }

        public PXAction<StkItemFilter> OpenStockItem;
        [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Open Stock Item")]
        public virtual void openStockItem()
        {
            StkItemUpdateDet det = StkItemUpdates.Current;
            InventoryItemMaint invtItemMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
            invtItemMaint.Item.Current = invtItemMaint.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(det.InventoryID);
            if (invtItemMaint.Item.Current != null)
            {
                throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(invtItemMaint, true, "Stock Item")
                {
                    Mode = PXBaseRedirectException.WindowMode.NewWindow
                };
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Static Methods

        public static void UpdateStkItems(List<StkItemUpdateDet> stkItemUpdateDets)
        {
            StkItemUpdateMaint stkItemUpdateMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<StkItemUpdateMaint>();
            InventoryItemMaint invtItemMaint = PXGraph.CreateInstance<InventoryItemMaint>();
            
            foreach (StkItemUpdateDet det in stkItemUpdateDets)
            {
                stkItemUpdateMaint.Clear();
                invtItemMaint.Clear();
                
                StkItemUpdateHdr hdr = stkItemUpdateMaint.UpdateHdr.Current = stkItemUpdateMaint.UpdateHdr.Search<StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID>(det.UpdateID);
                InventoryItem invtItem = invtItemMaint.Item.Current = invtItemMaint.Item.Search<InventoryItem.inventoryID>(det.InventoryID);
                
                if (hdr == null || invtItem == null) continue;

                BasisPricing.BasisPricing_InventoryItemExt invtItemExt = PXCache<InventoryItem>.GetExtension<BasisPricing.BasisPricing_InventoryItemExt>(invtItem);

                bool fieldUpdated = false;
                if (invtItemExt.UsrManualCost != det.ManualCost)
                {
                    invtItemMaint.Item.Cache.SetValueExt<BasisPricing.BasisPricing_InventoryItemExt.usrManualCost>(invtItem, det.ManualCost);
                    fieldUpdated = true;
                }

                if (invtItem.RecPrice != det.MSRP)
                {
                    invtItemMaint.Item.Cache.SetValueExt<InventoryItem.recPrice>(invtItem, det.MSRP);
                    fieldUpdated = true;
                }

                if (fieldUpdated)
                {
                    invtItemMaint.Item.Cache.Update(invtItem);
                    invtItemMaint.Actions.PressSave();

                    det.LastUpdatedDateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    stkItemUpdateMaint.UpdateDets.Cache.Update(det);
                    stkItemUpdateMaint.Actions.PressSave();
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Here is my ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="IN507500.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_IN507500" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/FormView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="INCostPriceUpdate.StkItemUpdateProcess"
        PrimaryView="Filter"
        >
        <CallbackCommands>
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="OpenUpdate" Visible="false" />
            <px:PXDSCallbackCommand Name="OpenStockItem" Visible="false" />
        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phF" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXFormView ID="form" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" DataMember="Filter" Width="100%" AllowAutoHide="false">
        <Template>
            <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule1" runat="server" StartRow="True"/>
            <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule2" runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="85px" ControlSize="XM" />
            <px:PXSelector ID="PXSelector1" runat="server" DataField="UpdateID" CommitChanges="true" />
            <px:PXSelector ID="FilterVendorID" runat="server" DataField="VendorID" CommitChanges="true" />
            <px:PXSelector ID="FilterInventoryID" runat="server" DataField="InventoryID" CommitChanges="true" />

            <px:PXLayoutRule ID="PXLayoutRule3" runat="server" StartColumn="True" LabelsWidth="75px" />
            <px:PXDateTimeEdit ID="FilterFromDate" runat="server" DataField="FromEffectiveDate" CommitChanges="true" />
            <px:PXDateTimeEdit ID="FilterToDate" runat="server" DataField="ToEffectiveDate" CommitChanges="true" />
        </Template>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="30" />
    </px:PXFormView>
    <px:PXGrid ID="StkItemUpdateDetGrid" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="650px" SyncPosition="true" AdjustPageSize="Auto" AllowPaging="false" SkinID="PrimaryInquire" DataSourceID="ds">
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="StkItemUpdates">
                <Columns>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Selected" Type="CheckBox" TextAlign="Center" CommitChanges="true" AllowCheckAll="true" AllowMove="false" AllowResize="false" AllowSort="false" AllowShowHide="false"></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="StkItemUpdateHdr__VendorID" Width="140" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="UpdateID" LinkCommand="OpenUpdate" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="StkItemUpdateHdr__EffectiveDate" Width="90" />
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" CommitChanges="true" Width="150" LinkCommand="OpenStockItem" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryDescr" Width="200" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="ManualCost" Width="100" CommitChanges="true" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="MSRP" Width="100" CommitChanges="true" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CurrManualCost" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="CurrMSRP" Width="100" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="LastUpdatedDateTime" Width="150" DisplayFormat="g" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="DefaultVendor" Width="150" ></px:PXGridColumn>
                    <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AvailVendors" Width="250" ></px:PXGridColumn></Columns>
            
                <RowTemplate>
                    <px:PXSelector AllowEdit="True" runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector1" DataField="DefaultVendor" ></px:PXSelector>
                    <px:PXSelector runat="server" ID="CstPXSelector3" DataField="StkItemUpdateHdr__VendorID" AllowEdit="True" ></px:PXSelector></RowTemplate></px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

Here is the main DAC used on the Processing Screen:

```
public class StkItemUpdateDet : IBqlTable
{
    #region Selected
    [PXBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Selected")]
    public virtual bool? Selected { get; set; }
    public abstract class selected : PX.Data.BQL.BqlBool.Field<selected> { }
    #endregion

    #region UpdateID
    [PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update ID", Enabled = false)]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID))]
    [PXParent(typeof(SelectFrom<StkItemUpdateHdr>.
        Where<StkItemUpdateHdr.updateID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateDet.updateID.FromCurrent>>)
    )]
    public virtual string UpdateID { get; set; }
    public abstract class updateID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<updateID> { }
    #endregion

    #region InventoryID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
    [PXDefault]
    [PXSelector(
        typeof(
            SearchFor<InventoryItem.inventoryID>.
                In<SelectFrom<InventoryItem>.
                    InnerJoin<POVendorInventory>.
                        On<POVendorInventory.inventoryID.IsEqual<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>.
                    Where<InventoryItem.stkItem.IsEqual<True>.
                        And<POVendorInventory.vendorID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID.FromCurrent>>.
                        And<POVendorInventory.active.IsEqual<True>>>>
        ),
        typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
        typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
        typeof(InventoryItem.itemClassID),
        typeof(InventoryItem.itemType),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD)
    )]
    [PXRestrictor(
        typeof(Where<InventoryItem.stkItem.IsEqual<True>.
                    And<POVendorInventory.vendorID.IsEqual<StkItemUpdateHdr.vendorID.FromCurrent>>.
                    And<POVendorInventory.active.IsEqual<True>>>),
        Messages.InvalidVendorItemPair)]
    public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class inventoryID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<inventoryID> { }
    #endregion

    #region InventoryDesc
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Descr.", Enabled = false)]
    [InventoryDescr]
    public virtual string InventoryDescr { get; set; }
    public abstract class inventoryDescr : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<inventoryDescr> { }
    #endregion

    #region ManualCost
    [PXDBDecimal(6)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "New Manual Cost")]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.000000")]
    public virtual decimal? ManualCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class manualCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<manualCost> { }
    #endregion

    #region MSRP
    [PXDBDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "New MSRP")]
    [PXDefault(TypeCode.Decimal, "0.00")]
    public virtual decimal? MSRP { get; set; }
    public abstract class msrp : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<msrp> { }
    #endregion

    #region CurrManualCost
    [PXDecimal(6)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Current Manual Cost", Enabled = false)]
    [ManualCost]
    public virtual decimal? CurrManualCost { get; set; }
    public abstract class currManualCost : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<currManualCost> { }
    #endregion

    #region CurrMSRP
    [PXDecimal(2)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Current MSRP", Enabled = false)]
    [MSRP]
    public virtual decimal? CurrMSRP { get; set; }
    public abstract class currMSRP : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDecimal.Field<currMSRP> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastUpdatedDateTime
    [PXDBDate(PreserveTime = true, UseTimeZone = false)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Update Last Executed", Enabled = false)]
    public virtual DateTime? LastUpdatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastUpdatedDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<lastUpdatedDateTime> { }
    #endregion

    #region DefaultVendor
    [PXInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Default Vendor", Enabled = false)]
    [PXSelector(
        typeof(SearchFor<Vendor.bAccountID>),
        SubstituteKey = typeof(Vendor.acctCD)
    )]
    public int? DefaultVendor { get; set; }
    public abstract class defaultVendor : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<defaultVendor> { }
    #endregion  

    #region AvailVendors
    [PXString]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Available Vendors", Enabled = false)]
    [AvailVendors]
    public string AvailVendors { get; set; }
    public abstract class availVendors : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<availVendors> { }
    #endregion  

    #region System Fields

    #region CreatedByID
    [PXDBCreatedByID()]
    public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<createdByID> { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByScreenID
    [PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
    public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdByScreenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<createdByScreenID> { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedDateTime
    [PXDBCreatedDateTime()]
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<createdDateTime> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByID
    [PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
    public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedByID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<lastModifiedByID> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByScreenID
    [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
    public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<lastModifiedByScreenID> { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedDateTime
    [PXDBLastModifiedDateTime()]
    public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : PX.Data.BQL.BqlDateTime.Field<lastModifiedDateTime> { }
    #endregion

    #region tstamp
    [PXDBTimestamp()]
    public virtual byte[] tstamp { get; set; }
    public abstract class Tstamp : PX.Data.BQL.BqlByteArray.Field<Tstamp> { }
    #endregion

    #region Noteid
    [PXNote()]
    public virtual Guid? Noteid { get; set; }
    public abstract class noteid : PX.Data.BQL.BqlGuid.Field<noteid> { }
    #endregion

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Possibly a key and/or join issue, I would suggest to simplify the Processing data view until 'red dot' disappears and then re-integrate the removed elements.

Comment: When the framework can't identify the records based on key fields it tends to misbehave in the ways you describe. Make sure each record has a proper unique key.